# How to connect to sql database on website/or other pc

Tags: c#, sql, database

I've searched and I couldn't find!

I want to make a connection between c# asp to a website database and I don't know if this should be the right connection string:

```
("server=servaname;uid=database user id;password=pass;database=databasename");
```

If that's the correct string , how can I connect to a website database? I've checked my phpadmin page on website(created new database) , but I only see

```
servername = just an normal name not ip or address.
```

Could someone explain and help me? thanks.
And , I also want to know how to connect to a pc database? I mean If my asp site is online on a domain , I Want to connect to database hosted on a pc.
For sql

Thanks.

Comment: Change the servername into IP address of remote computer

Comment: What is "a website database", what is it about `server=servername` that you don't understand and *what error do you get* when you try to connect?

Comment: What's a website database? It's not at all clear where your problems are. Are you using ASP or ASP.net? Web searches on "connecting asp to sql database" for example returned many results that may help you.

Comment: You need to read about networking and [hostname (DNS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname).

Answer (score 0):

this might help you.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

It would also help if you included what Kind of database you wanted to connect to and I am a little confused about phpadmin and the question is tagged c#

Comment: I use asp.net , If I host my asp on a domain and I use localhost will it work?:-?

Comment: is the database on localhost ? whats the name of your sql server ?

Comment: nope the database is not on local host , I just want to debug my asp and receive and send information to a database located on a domain webhosting.

Comment: Ok so your website is on a domain ? and you want to run it locally ? Is a domain like www.google.com or a AD domain ?

Comment: yes like name.com , and I just want to learn by working with the database from the domain

Comment: yea you can do that sounds like its a prod database might not want too